# Outlook, gmail basic issue (caused the code)

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-email

I found issue when try to create my first email template design that I think it caused the code (I am so new for that).

This is the screenshot:

> [image]

Wondering why the "blog post" and "sidebar" section are not same width the "table section" above?

**I used the code something like this:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Mail 2</title>
    <style type="text/css">
some style
    </style>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Mail 2">
</head>
<body width="100%" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
            <v:background fill="t">
               <v:fill type="tile" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-6styRrYxl3U/T7Sg_Cbww0I/AAAAAAAAAkE/UWVWEJDfSj0/h120/header-bg.png" />
            </v:background>
        <![endif]-->
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table align="center" width="600">
                <tr>
                <td>
                This is above table section that shown correct
                </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <table width="600">
                <tr>
                <td width="340" colspan="1" class="blog post">
                This is below section that shown not correct as above. Blog post section that looks out of the box.
                </td>

                <td width="200" colspan="1" class="blog post">
                <table>
                    </tr>
                        <td>
                            Blah blah. This is sidebar section that looks out of the box.
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have two rows and two column why make it so complicated?

```
<table width="596px" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
   <td>Content 1</td>
   <td>Content 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Content 3</td>
   <td>Content 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Place whatever content you want in each of the "content spots" and job done. You have far too many td's and tr's, best practise is to keep it simple. I would also suggest giving the table a width of 596px rather than 100% as this can cause display issues with certain email clients.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a couple errors in your code.

1.) In bottom 2nd table, you had `</tr>` instead of `<tr>`

2.) top table was align center, but bottom did not have align declare

3.) On bottom table, td widths add up to 540, not the declared 600

I believe the errors above were causing the issue.  If not, I would need a bit more info into what exactly is inside each table as it could be image size, further errors in the code inside nested tables, etc.

See code snippet below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Mail 2</title>
    <style type="text/css">
some style
    </style>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Mail 2">
</head>
<body width="100%" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
            <v:background fill="t">
               <v:fill type="tile" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-6styRrYxl3U/T7Sg_Cbww0I/AAAAAAAAAkE/UWVWEJDfSj0/h120/header-bg.png" />
            </v:background>
        <![endif]-->
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table align="center" width="600">
                <tr>
                <td>
                This is above table section that shown correct
                </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <table align="center" width="600">
                <tr>
                <td width="340" class="blog post">
                This is below section that shown not correct as above. Blog post section that looks out of the box.
                </td>

                <td width="200" class="blog post">
                <table>
                <tr>
                        <td>
                            Blah blah. This is sidebar section that looks out of the box.
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```